# Why is there a .steampath in my home directory?

Tags: steam, symbolic-link, dynamic-linking, hard-link

In the terminal, I see a broken link which is named `.steampath`, I didn't remove `/home/user/.steam/sdk32/steam`, but it is gone.
[image]

Why is the `.steampath` there?

Should I remove it?

Comment: Seems to be quite common and maybe a bug that has not been important enough to get fixed. You could safely remove it, but that doesn't help as it seems to be generated every time steam is started. You can simply ignore it.

Answer (score 11):

This is a known Steam issue: the symlink is created and is intentionally broken for compatibility with older Steamworks SDK that some games are still built with.

There is a [bug report on this issue](https://github.com/anyc/steam-overlay/issues/206), and also a [tracking list of games](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/issues/5245) that need to be updated.